# SQL Server - Inserting from one table to another where values are NOT null

Tags: sql-server, database, stored-procedures, sql-insert, sql-null

I have TABLE A which I am attempting to join it's values into TABLE B. Table B does not allow nullables under column `Item`. There are a few items in `Table A` that has a NULL value for `item`. I am attempting to insert into this table and set a condition to not include the values that are equal to NULL.

Here is an of Table A:

```
+---+-----------------+
|ID | SizeID |Item    |
+---------------------+
|   |        |        +
| 1 |  22    | Clothing
+---------------------+
| 2 |   2    | Shoes  |
+---------------------+
| 3 |   11   |  NULL  |
+---------------------+
| 4 |   9    |  NULL  |
+---------------------+
| 5 |   10   |  Hats  |
+---+--------+--------+
```

Table B has the same naming convention of columns. I get an error when running an insert query due to some of the null values and Table B does not allow Nullables. So I attempted to work around this issue by using `Where Item <> NULL` but when running this query I am having 0 rows affected.

How can I alter my query in order to insert into Table B IF `Item` is NOT NULL

Here is an example of my query :

```
INSERT INTO dbo.TableB ([SizeID], [Item])
SELECT(SizeID as SizeID, Item as Item)
FROM dbo.TableA
WHERE Item <> NULL
```

Comment: `WHERE Item IS NOT NULL`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does not do what you think it does:

```
WHERE Item <> NULL
```

In SQL, nothing is equal to `null` - same goes for other comparison operators (not equal, greater than, less than, between, and so on).

You can think of `null` as *undefined*, or *unknown*. Typically `null <> null` produces a `null` result (which, in a `where` clause, behaves identically to `false`).

To check a value against `null`, you need special construct `is [not] null`.

So:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.TableB (SizeID, Item)
SELECT SizeID, Item
FROM dbo.TableA
WHERE Item IS NOT NULL
```

Note that I removed the parentheses around the columns in the `SELECT` clause, as well as the aliases, which are unnecessary.